# Need a svg figure

Tags: svg, path, viewbox

I have a figure with 100% width. And I need her inverted version. I rely on your help please.

```
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<path d="M0 0 C50 90 100 0 100 0 Z"/>
</svg>
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexSotona/62j6sq9L/)

Comment: Inverted in what way? Black becomes white and vice versa or reflected about an axis?

Comment: i update my jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/AlexSotona/62j6sq9L/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw it in white on a black background then.

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <rect width="100" height="40" fill="black"/>
<path d="M0 0 C50 90 100 0 100 0 Z" fill="white"/>
</svg>
```

or alternatively you could just keep drawing round the edge...

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M0 0 C50 90 100 0 100 0 v40 h-100 v-40Z" fill="black"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: The whole point is that I need a figure on a transparent background . But thanks anyway.)))

Comment: Saying so in the question would have helped.